# Performing git on a dir

Tags: git, svn, scripting

I'm trying to script a `git pull` at  $dir. It should be the equivalent of `svn update $dir`.

Does any one know any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$1
pushd $dir
git pull
popd
```

Note that if $dir is a subdirectory, this will update the whole tree, not just that subdirectory.

Comment: the problem with that type of solution is that git will call exit directly, so popd will never be called.

Comment: maybe its because i'm on windows. (wanders away in shame)

Comment: i don't see why this wouldn't work on windows too (after you change it deal with the different syntax for arguments and environment variables).  make sure you're using git.exe, rather than a batch/cmd file.